# How do I scrape the data for each personal links listed in a webpage using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, html-parsing

I am about to get the details of each lawyer in https://chambers.com/all-lawyers-asia-pacific-8. There are about 5k+ lawyers listed. But their details are listed in the associated links in the site. I don't have a problem scraping a single web page. However, it will take forever for me to visit each lawyer profile page and scrape them individually. Is there a way to loop this process?

I really don't know what to do because I was tasked to get the lawyer's name, the link to their profile, their law firm, and their ranks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) to boost up the process. It is possible that the site will ban you for too many requests. In that case, you should use a different user agent for each thread or make requests via tor or vpn.

Answer (score 0):

Use `selenium webdriver`.
With `find_elements(by.xpath)` get all href attributes of all records as a list and loop through them in a for each.
In a loop use href value to open details page `webdriver.get(href_value)`. That will open page with record details where you scrape needed info.

Comment: This won't solve the problem. He said that `it will take forever for me to visit each lawyer profile page and scrape them individually`.

Comment: it will not last that _forever_ if you read all links before looping rather than scrape start page for next link 5k times as someone may do